# Jackson Find/Create Serializer for class from SerializerProvider

Tags: java, serialization, jackson

I'm using Spring 4 with Jackson 2.3. 
I wrote a custom JsonSerializer for the Optional wrapper.
It looks like follows:

```
@Override
public void serialize(Optional optional, com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
    if(optional.isPresent()){
        Object o = optional.get();
        Class<?> aClass = o.getClass();
        DefaultSerializerProvider.Impl sp = new DefaultSerializerProvider.Impl();

        // Cant find proper Serializer
        JsonSerializer<Object> serializer = sp.getUnknownTypeSerializer(aClass);

        serializer.serialize(o, jsonGenerator, serializerProvider);
    }else throw new EmptyException("Empty Option");
}
```

My problem is to get a proper Serializer for the optional value if present, so the Question is **how can I get a POJO serializer from SerializerProvider?**

My current Pojo looks:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class User {

private UUID uid;

private boolean valid;

private List<String> gids;
```

so no special anotations given

Comment: Where is the `Optional` in your POJO class? Could you show a little example where do you have `Optional` and what are you trying to do? I guess that example, which you showed does not work, does it?

Comment: It doesn't work, right. Optional is a nullable value wrapper [Optional<T>](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html). I want to throw a EmptyException if its empty. If not i want to find the coresponding Jackson converter for the object inside and let jackson serialize.

Comment: OK, I understand it. But I do not see where is `Optional` in your POJO class. Why you want to serialize it? Can you check `optional.isPresent()` before passing object to serialize? Could you add an example what are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm getting an Optional Object from every Db Request (over a Dao) so I want to get rid of it when it comes to serialisatzion, maybe thats too late. Any Idea how I can Intercept before Jackson gehts the object? So i when call optional.get() it returns the Object i want to serialize.